# Maven Jetty plugin configure repository

Tags: maven, plugins, repository, jetty

We use jetty plugin for local deployment of our application. Recently i added a repository in the pom and added dependencies both in the plugin section and the dependencies section outside as well, when i  build the war and deploy it on standalone app server everything works ok, however the same application when i try to run through the jetty application it throws me error for that particular dependency.
Is there any way that we can configure the external repositories to be used by the plugins in order to resolve the dependencies.

Thanks,
- Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue right, you can add a dependency to the jetty-maven-plugin itself and have it available to your application.  Something like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.14.v20161028</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>foo</groupId>
      <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```